# Entity Framework Feature CTP5 Append Model?

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-ctp5

I am using EF Feature CTP5 and need to be able to just append changes to the database structure when making changes to the model or my class objects?

Is there a way to do this or does it need to drop and recreate the database every time you make a change to the class objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as of CTP5 only *DropCreateDatabaseAlways* and *DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges* strategies are supported which essentially recreate your DB every time.

That said, EF team is actively working on a [*Code First Database Evolution (aka Migrations)*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/10/22/code-first-database-evolution-aka-migrations.aspx) feature which is exactly what you are looking for: Altering DB instead of dropping it. We likely get this feature in the RTM this year.

Comment: I sure hope so as that would be great.